# how to see which developers have done the most work in azure devops git?

Tags: git, azure, devops

We use jira for tickets and azure devops git.

Is there a way to query or get a report of lines of code added by each dev?  Not a great metric, but better than nothing.

There are some devs who appear to be doing very little work, but without looking at what each dev has done individually, we would like a rough metric to start.

Azure devops doesnt seem to have anything built in (and dashboard widgets like burn down dont work as we dont use its ticket system)

Maybe there is a way to see who has done the most commits, pull requests or added lines of code for a particular period?

Or may be we can query jira to get a report of completed tickets per developer for a period, or even most story points?

Comment: it is only barely better than nothing. Looking at lines of code probably only makes sense as a "justification" for looking more closely at an individuals work, but unless it's really zero it's very hard to think of it as a metric. E.g. work on some projects adds a lot of lines of code automatically through the IDE which is just XML or something... (I know this is tangential to your question)

Comment: agreed, but over a year, given the diversity of tasks, it should be easy to see who is not commiting many changes and therefor could be investigated in more detail.

Comment: As long as you keep in mind that e.g. someone who does a lot of code review or someone who has to fix the hardest-to-find bugs will necessarily have a lot fewer LoC, it could be fine, yeah

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you may look into the integration of ADO with Jira.
You may want to sync work items to Jira and get some reports on that.
Here is one the [plugins](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1223931/azure-devops-for-jira-integration-sync-migration-new-app?tab=overview&hosting=cloud) to look at.

[Another one](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1220515/azure-pipelines-for-jira?hosting=cloud&tab=overview) is for integration of the ADO pipelines with Jira issues.

There are some other also available.

If this doesn't work for you you may look into [Commit reports created by ADO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/commit-history?view=azure-devops) directly. From there you can use filters by date and author.

The same for **Pull requests** - you can build a [custom view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/view-pull-requests?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#define-a-custom-pull-request-view) for completed PRs.

Finally, if some of the DevOps guys spend more time on building or debugging something in the pipelines you may check [agent usage reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/usage-monitoring?view=azure-devops#view-usage) by user.

Answer (score -1):

As shared in the previous answer, without add-ons, Jira cannot report per developer. However, with most of the add-ons, you get some basic performance reporting that can be done. For instance, cycle time per developer, number of tickets resolved, time spent on each ticket (if you log work in Jira), etc.

Further, as you correctly highlighted, evaluating developer performance based on lines of code is not a great practice. It often encourages developers to write lengthy and complex code (so that number of lines they are checking-in increases), resulting in hard-to-read, complex code, increased technical debt and higher probability of defects in the long run. Also, ADO has in-built reporting only for work items, not for code commits. Therefore, the only way would be to use ADO APIs to fetch commit history and then use Excel to create reports.

There are some advanced performance metrics as well. These metrics tend to provide relatively greater insights compared to basic metrics, as advanced metrics analyze performance by analyzing ticket and commit history together. Here are a few of them:

Number of tickets resolved, cycle time, code check-ins, lines touched, story points burnt, files touched per developer (all in a single report)

Compare these metrics against the team's average, lowest and highest numbers.

Code churn rate per developer

Developers for whom 'remaining work' has marginally reduced

'Remaining work' burns down per developer.

Flag developers who have not logged in any work in the last few business days and have no code commits as well.